# Setting a div to height 100% using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a div's height 100% of the browser window using javascript. I have gone the CSS route it works but there seems to be cross browser issues with it.

my code so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resize() {

var div = document.getElementById("test");
div.height = window.innerHeight; 

}

window.onload = resize;

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="test"></div>

//--------------body close etc
```

the Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I have gone the CSS route it works but there seems to be cross browser issues with it."* Which issue? Also, what's the problem with the JS code you have?

Comment: Try with `div.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px"` instead.

Comment: You need px like @MaxArt is saying.. also.. it most likely isn't a cross browser issue of 100% height. It is most likely the interpretation. You have to make sure to 100% both HTML and BODY when doing height 100%. Then the container itself needs to be inside of the body nothing else and given height 100%. Usually a position absolute element is easiest to display this, but you can do it for many factors.

Comment: `#test{position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0}`

Comment: Thank you. it worked, I also added window.resize = resize on top of the window.onload and and now it adjusts perfectly to the window. Will also relook my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3jr5hyL/)**

change `div.height` to `div.style.height`

OR

**Javasrcipt**

```
document.getElementById("test").style.height = window.innerHeight+'px';
```